# VBA: Initialize Combo Box in worksheet

Tags: vba, combobox

I have an error during initialization and I do not get why this is not working:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets(1)


ws.ComboC15.AddItem "Technology"
end sub
```

It is very weird, the code should be correct. I have checked the combo name and it is "ComboC15".

In fact, this is the sub:

```
 Private Sub ComboC15_Change()
```

Ps: I also checked the sheet and it is the first sheet where I have the Combo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Worksheet` object in VBA doesn't have a property or method called `ComboC15`, as this is entirely your own invention. However, the individual ***worksheet*** object in your workbook, i.e. the sheet itself as a physical sheet and not as a VBA sheet, knows all about `ComboC15` since it's been dropped on it by you. Therefore, you need to access the worksheet object (notice the little **w**) and not the Worksheet object (notice the big **W**). <sup><sub>If it's confusing to read, imagine how confusing it is for me to try to explain this...</sub></sup>

To get access to the worksheet Object, you can do any of the following:

```
' Assuming "Sheet1" is the code name of the object. You can find this code name
' in the VBA editor. In the "Project Explorer" window, look under Microsoft
' Excel Objects. Your sheets are listed there in the form (for a blank, new
' workbook) "Sheet1 (Sheet1)". The bit *outside* the brackets is the code name.
Sheet1.ComboC15.AddItem "Technology"

' You can even call it directly from the "Worksheet" object by using the sheet
' index.
Worksheets(1).ComboC15.AddItem "Technology"
```

However, if you want to create a variable with it so you don't have to copy/paste the same thing over and over, declare it as an `Object` and not as a `Worksheet`. So do this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Dim ws As Object ' Declare ws as "Object"!

  Set ws = Worksheets(1)

  ws.ComboC15.AddItem "Technology"

End Sub
```

The following SO Q&A explains a bit more about the different kind of sheet names:

- [Excel tab sheet names vs. Visual Basic sheet names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649844/excel-tab-sheet-names-vs-visual-basic-sheet-names)

and I hope [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/) might give you a better insight on how to reference different kinds of objects in VBA.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I had no idea about that!