# Having trouble using designer and inputng VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone help me get my userform to submit into this table from cal worksheet?

```
Private Sub cmdbutton_submitform_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    'Make Sheet2 active
    Sheet2.Activate
    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    'Transfer information
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = txtbox_number.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = txtbox_rank.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtbox_Name.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = txtbox_height.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = txtbox_weight.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = txtbox_right_rm.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = txtbox_left_rm.Value
End Sub
```

[image: VBA_code-submit]

[image: table_i_want_to_load_info]

Comment: I can screen shot my vba code I am using

Comment: Private Sub cmdbutton_submitform_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet2 active
Sheet2.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = txtbox_number.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = txtbox_rank.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtbox_Name.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = txtbox_height.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = txtbox_weight.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = txtbox_right_rm.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = txtbox_left_rm.Value

End Sub

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Do you get an error or...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused with sheet codenames and sheet names (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649844/excel-tab-sheet-names-vs-visual-basic-sheet-names)). Try

```
Private Sub cmdbutton_submitform_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        'Determine emptyRow
        emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) + 1
        'Transfer information
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = txtbox_number.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = txtbox_rank.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = txtbox_Name.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = txtbox_height.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = txtbox_weight.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = txtbox_right_rm.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = txtbox_left_rm.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome insight thank you... im learning everyday. Never touched vba until today

Answer (score 0):

Using [Worksheet.Activate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838003.aspx) likely loses the parent form reference that is required to correctly get the text box data from the user form. Within this `Private Sub` you should be able to reference `Sheet2` by its Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) and use `Me` to reference the user form as the parent of the text boxes.

```
Private Sub cmdbutton_submitform_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    'Reference Sheet2 by CodeName as the parent worksheet of the .Cells
    With Sheet2
        'Determine emptyRow
        emptyRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Transfer information
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Me.txtbox_number.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Me.txtbox_rank.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Me.txtbox_Name.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Me.txtbox_height.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = Me.txtbox_weight.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = Me.txtbox_right_rm.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = Me.txtbox_left_rm.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I found it a little odd that you were identifying the worksheet with a Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) rather than a Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx). I've included a couple of links to make sure you are using the naming conventions correctly. In any event, I've use a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to avoid repeatedly reidentifying the parent worksheet.