# Copy The Code from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that create another sheet and paste the code of the second sheet on it, the program also will delete the sheet if it already exists

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Calcs").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Calcs"
End With

Dim CodeCopy As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim CodePaste As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim numLines As Integer

Set CodeCopy = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet2").CodeModule
Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Calcs").CodeModule

numLines = CodeCopy.CountOfLines

CodePaste.AddFromString CodeCopy.Lines(1, numLines)
```

Is not working and I dont know why

Comment: What error do you get? Have you run the code in debug? Have you checked [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813969) ?

Comment: Would it not be easier to create a Very Hidden worksheet containing the code you need and then just copy the whole sheet and rename it as needed?

Comment: The error is
@genespos Run- Time Error 9
Subscript out of range,

By using the debug the error is about the line when I set the target sheet (Sheet calcs)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I dont know how to do it, I am just started to learn how to use VBA

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working because of the name of your sheet. In the VBA Project window you can see that your sheets have two names: **Sheet1 (Sheet1)**. So when you add your sheet and rename it, the name will be Sheet##(Calcs) but when you write `ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Calcs").CodeModule` you need to use "Sheet##" which is the codename instead of "Calcs".
It is better explained here:
[Excel tab sheet names vs. Visual Basic sheet names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649844/excel-tab-sheet-names-vs-visual-basic-sheet-names)

What I suggest is to declare your sheet when you create it and write `...VBComponents(TheNameYouDeclared.CodeName).CodeModule`

The code you gave us plus what I suggest gives you:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Calcs").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Calcs"
End With

Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calcs")

Dim CodeCopy As String
Dim CodePaste As String
Dim numLines As Integer

CodeCopy = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule
CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(MySheet.CodeName).CodeModule

numLines = CodeCopy.CountOfLines

CodePaste.AddFromString CodeCopy.Lines(1, numLines)
```

Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Create a template worksheet containing the code you need - then just copy this to create your new sheet.

In my code I have used the codename of the template sheet rather than the name that appears on the tab (which can be changed outside the VBE) - it's the name not in brackets in your `Microsoft Excel Objects` and can be updated with the `(Name)` property in the `Properties` tab.

```
Sub Test()

    If WorkSheetExists("Calcs") Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calcs").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    With shtTemplate 'Use codename rather than actual name.
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = "Calcs"

End Sub

Public Function WorkSheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional WrkBk As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    If WrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Set WrkBk = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wrkSht = WrkBk.Worksheets(SheetName)
        WorkSheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
        Set wrkSht = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```