# How to refer to a Excel Worksheet by its VBA Object Name in another Workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, reference, worksheet

I have two Excel Workbooks:

1. `Source.xlsx`
2. `Tool.xlsm`

`Source.xlsx` contains a Worksheet with the VBA Object Name `shtTests`:

[image: Screenshot of VBA Properties for shtTests]

Let's assume that in `Tool.xlsm` I have a variable that contains a reference to the Workbook stored in `Source.xlsx`:

```
Dim wkbSource as Workbook
Set wkbSource = GetSourceWorkbook() ' Some function that gives a reference to the workbook
```

**Core Question:** How can I reference `shtTests` within `Tool.xlsm` by using `shtTests`' *VBA Name*?

---

Or to formulate the question as code... assume you have this code snippet:

```
Dim wkbSourceShtTests as Worksheet
Set wkbSourceShtTests = GetShtTestsFromWkbSources(wkbSources)
```

**Question:** What does `GetShtTestsFromWkbSources` have to look like?

---

**Note:** I do **not** want to reference it by its Excel Name like you would do using `wkbSources.Worksheets("Test Cloning")` because people might change its Excel Name some day.

Comment: You'd write a loop that goes through each sheet in that workbook and compares its codename with the one you are interested in. Or set a reference to the VBA project of the other workbook and refer to it directly as a member of that project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel tab sheet names vs. Visual Basic sheet names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649844/excel-tab-sheet-names-vs-visual-basic-sheet-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted a function instead of setting up the trusted access then this would probably work:

```
Sub example()
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Set wkbSource = GetSourceWorkbook()

Dim wkbSourceShtTests As Worksheet
Set wkbSourceShtTests = GetShtTestsFromWkbSources(wkbSource, "shtTests")

End Sub

Function GetShtTestsFromWkbSources(wkbk As Workbook, codename As String) As Worksheet
For Each sht In wkbk.Sheets
    If sht.codename = codename Then Set GetShtTestsFromWkbSources = sht
Next
End Function
```

Comment: While I like both solutions, they both use the `Worksheets` collection for looking up the respective sheet. So I prefer this solution because it requires less pre-requisites. Thanks a lot both to CLR and to Siddharth Rout.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbThat As Workbook
    Dim wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim wsCodeName As String

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbThat = Workbooks("Book4") '<~~ Change this to relevant workbook

    wsCodeName = "ShtSheets"

    Set wsThat = wbThat.Worksheets(CStr(wbThat.VBProject.VBComponents(wsCodeName).Properties(7)))

    Debug.Print wsThat.Name
End Sub
```

**Note**: For this to work, you need to enable access to Visual Basic Projects

On the `File` menu Excel, Click `Options|Trust Center|Trust Center Settings|Macro Settings`, Check the box "Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model"

Comment: Note that you have to have trusted access to the VBA project for that to work of course.