# Returning a column number from a table using the =COLUMN function

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function in Excel that returns the column number of a table based on the column header.
The table is called Config and the table column header is value. The below will return to me the column number in excel.

```
=COLUMN(Config[Value])-COLUMN(Config)+1
```

Could anybody let me know how this can be used in VBA?
I was hoping i could use something like ...

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Column
```

but it seems `Column` is not available for me to use.

Would anyone have any ideas on this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using a table (`ListObject`), you can refer to a `ListColumn` by its header. If you need the column number, you can use `ListColumn.Range.Column` - something like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim lc As ListColumn
    Dim col As Long

    Set lc = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Data1")
    col = lc.Range.Column
    Debug.Print col
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats awesome. Thank you. Is it possible to keep "Sheet1" dynamic. Like, in case someone changes the name of the sheet. I tried to use something like... `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.ListObjects` but it does not seem to work. Would you know the syntax for this?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649844/excel-tab-sheet-names-vs-visual-basic-sheet-names/2652524) might be useful - you could reference the sheet by its `CodeName`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477794/refer-to-sheet-using-codename) is a similar answer.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I checked that like and i see that Sheet1 is a reference code that remains the same even if the sheet name changes. When i run the following however `Set lc = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Config").ListColumns("Value")`, i get a **Subscript out of range error**. Would you have any idea why this might be happening??

Comment: If you're using the `CodeName`, refer to `Sheet1` directly - `Sheet1.ListObjects...`, not `Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects...`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for getting the column would be something like

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Column
```

to get the column number of cell B1.

If you use named ranges this will work too:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("NameOfRange").Column
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to reference an actual table so if somebody was to move the table within the sheet it would be able to pick up the Value using the Table name and associated column header as a reference. Is this possible?? (apologies for not being clearer on that in my original post)

Answer (score 0):

I used a much simpler method:

```
=COLUMNS(X[[#Headers],[A]:[B]])

Where:
 X is the Table name
 A is the name of the 1st column 
 B is the name of the column you need.
```

This formula is dynamic

Comment: This question is about VBA, not about formulas.