# "Run-time error '424': Object required" in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an enquiry sheet for users to check their own data. When user inputting some information which fits to the data list, the rest of their data will show up.

I've type the code as below and I guess probably it's lacking something because the error code "Run-time error '424': Object required" keeps popping up. And I have no idea what's lacking. Here's the code:

```vb
Sub EnquiryChecking()
    Dim i As Integer

    If (Sheet1.Cells(3, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 1)) And (Sheet1.Cells(4, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 4)) And (Sheet1.Cells(5, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 5)) Then
        Sheet1.Cells(7, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 2)
        Sheet1.Cells(8, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 3)
        Sheet1.Cells(9, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 6)
        Sheet1.Cells(10, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 7)
        Sheet1.Cells(11, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 8)
        Sheet1.Cells(12, 3) = DataList.Cells(i, 9)
    Else
        Sheet1.Cells(14, 2) = "Error Input"
    End If
End Sub
```

Many thanks!

A further update:
I added a `for` loop for `i` and now the code can run. But now the `Sheet1.Cell` doesn't show the `DataList.Cell` data (even the input is not correct, it doesn't show "Error Input". What happened? Also, what should I add if I want to show the data instantly in the cell?
Here's the code:

```vb
Sub EnquiryChecking()    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To i
        If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DataList").Cells(i, 1)) And (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DataList").Cells(i, 4)) And (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DataList").Cells(i, 5)) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 3) = Worksheets("DataList").Cells(i, 2)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, 3) = Worksheets("DataList").Cells(i, 3)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 3) = Worksheets("DataList").Cells(i, 6)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 3) = Worksheets("DataList").Cells(i, 7)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, 3) = Worksheets("DataList").Cells(i, 8)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, 3) = Worksheets("DataList").Cells(i, 9)
            Exit For
        Else
            Sheet1.Cells(14, 2) = "Error Input"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you declare the value of i?

Comment: @DarrellH, I thought the dim is the declaration?

Comment: No.  Dim tells what kind of variable i will be.  Somewhere you need to declare the value, otherwise i could be 0 or nothing, which will not make sense.  You can either pass the value or declare i=1 or for i=1 to 10, etc.

Comment: @DarrellH: You mean "initialise" or "assign" instead of "declare" the variable. Dragonfly is correct - the variable is declared. However, as you note, it is never assigned a value, so the default value is "0", which is invalid in `Cells`.

Comment: @DarrellH I got it.

Comment: @AJD you are right. I added the for loop and there's no error now. But I now don't understand why the cells don't show the data from Data.List...?

Comment: `For i = 1 to i` is just plain wrong. You need `For i = 1 to _<something>_` to make this work. Only you know what that _<something>_ is.

Comment: Thank you very much, @AJD. it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `DataList` by `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DataList")` to avoid getting that error.

Refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2649871/5331061) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. But but I got run-time error '1004' this time...?

Comment: Many thanks! I modified to Worksheets("DataList") to point as worksheet and it works fine.

Comment: Arguably, addressing the sheets by their [code name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481428/11683) (which `DataList` would be) is better than using the user-specified name which can be easily changed by users. It's just that you need to put `DataList` in the sheet's "Code name" property first which the OP apparently didn't do.