# savefig png where its file name is exactly the same as the excel sheet for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, savefig

I have an excel (screen shot below) file with two sheets and tried to plot the data from each sheets using for in loop. I  already succeeded creating two plots from these two sheets using this code below.

[image]

The problem is I also want to automatically save the plots into different png files where each png file name is exactly as the same as the sheet name from the excel. The png file name that I got is '83' and '95' not 'E1' nor 'E4. Screenshot below.
[image]'

Before the savefig there is two more for in loop for annotating. Does these two loops variable need to be changed?

thank you in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path ='F:\Backup\JN\TOR\TOR HLS.xlsx'
data= pd.ExcelFile(path)

sheets = data.sheet_names
    
for i in sheets:
    well=pd.read_excel(data, sheet_name=i)
    plt.plot(well['T'], well['mdpl pt'], marker='o', color='blue')
    plt.plot(well['P'], well['mdpl pt'], marker='o', color='red')
    for i, txt in enumerate(well['csg']):
        plt.annotate(txt, ((well['x csg']+5)[i], well['mdpl csg'][i]))
    for i, txt in enumerate(well['liner']):
        plt.annotate(txt, ((well['x liner']+5)[i], well['mdpl liner'][i]))
    plt.savefig(str(i), dpi=300, transparent='True')
    plt.close(i)
```

Comment: A and B is your name of sheet?

Comment: Hi Karthik, actually the sheet name is more than that

Comment: Please can you share ss of your excel sheet to make it more understandable

Comment: I don't have your Excel file, but it seems to work as expected for me... 
Do '83' and '95' refer to anything else in your file, rather than the sheet names?

Comment: oh sorry I think I oversimplified things

Comment: There can be a difference between the Excel sheet name and the Excel sheet codename - I have run into this before; could be related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649844/excel-tab-sheet-names-vs-visual-basic-sheet-names

Comment: I already edit, please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a snippet following your code and it works well for me and it creates 2 images with name `E3` and `E4`  as my sheet names are E3 and E4. I have attached my excel data as output also. Please check it too

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
path ='HLS.xlsx'
data= pd.ExcelFile(path)
sheets = data.sheet_names
print(sheets)
#['E3', 'E4']

for i in sheets:
    well=pd.read_excel(data, sheet_name=i)
    print(well)
    plt.plot(well['A'], well['B'], color='blue')
    plt.savefig(i)
    plt.close(i)

#well
#E3 first #E4 second
"""   A  B
   0  1  6
   1  2  5
   2  3  4
   3  4  3
   4  5  2
   5  6  1
      A  B
   0  6  1
   1  5  2
   2  4  3
   3  3  4
   4  2  5
   5  1  6"""
```